# Install postfix in CentOS 7 without maria-db

Tags: postfix-mta, centos7

I am trying to install postfix using yum in CentOS 7. I'm using a version of mysql (5.5.28) which is installed directly from a rpm file.

The default postfix has a dependency on mariadb. Since mariadb conflicts with mysql I'm unable to use this. I tried using the centosplus repository which has mysql support. After installing compat-mysql rpm, I am able to install postfix using following command:

> yum install  --exclude=mariadb-libs --exclude=mysql-community-libs
>   postfix

But after this when I try to start postfix I get the following error:

> /usr/sbin/postconf: relocation error: /usr/sbin/postconf: symbol
>   mysql_real_connect, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file
>   libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference

I am kind of stuck at here. Can any one please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need all required packages. Install all deendency packages.

Note that Installing Mariadb does mot mean you need it running. It will take only space on disk.

Comment: I understand installing maridab-libs will resolve this. But I am unable to install mariadb-libs because it is giving a conflict with mysql

Comment: another solution is to change mysql to mariadb- I am using mariadb for years and it is better than mysql. however i agree, this is NOT correct answer to the question beuse is kind of - "do instead" way :)

Comment: and yet another solution is to find old rpm of postfix thatvdoes not need mysql. or to install postfix from source

Comment: Sorry for late response. I couldn't manage to get it done using mysql 5.5. I upgraded to mysql 5.6 using yum (oracle yum repository). With that I could install postfix from centosplus repository. Thanks for the responses.